# Find which user viewed my website (on private network)

Tags: networking, view, private

I have private network at work, something like : `\\\company\folder1\\....`
We also have Active directory set-up with all the users and etc.

I want to make a simple blank website which only tells me which user have entered my website.

a list like:

```
user1
user2
...
```

My big question is - how can I know which people viewed my page?

Comment: You will get their IP address. Based on that, you can find the computer. That's about as far as it goes. You won't get their Active Directory credentials when they perform a web-request.

Comment: @GolezTrol Thanks for your answer, how can I get their ip address? find the computer with the IP address won't be an issue for me